# session does not appear in the label

Tags: c#, asp.net

I created session to move data between pages using c# asp.net  but the result does  not appear and the program does not give me error in the code

first page code:

```
Session["New1"] = desc1.Text;
```

to send data to Label  in Second page 
code:

```
 var userType = (string)Session["New1"];
        if (userType != null)
        {
            Label1.Text = userType.ToString() ;
        }
        else
        {
            // test "2" etc
        }
```

Comment: where is this code on the first and second pages?

Comment: in the first page inside method onclick

Comment: the secound code inside page load method

Comment: Make sure the website isn't stopped between both page actions. A "stop" would occur if you are e.g. running in debug mode from Visual Studio, then end the application, then set the other page as Start page, and run the application again. A "stop" will clear all Application state from memory (including Session data).

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
  if (Session["New1"]!= null)
        {
            Label1.Text = Session["New1"].ToString() ;
        }
        else
        {
            // test "2" etc
        }
```

Comment: it gives me an erorr Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: now try it,if it does not work than it mean you are directly hitting this code without calling that page in which your session get filled by your textbox.

Comment: @user6159724 if the error is Object reference not set to an instance of an object, session is null

Answer (score 0):

Try explicitly checking of your Session variable exists before attempting to use it to avoid any null-reference issues :

```
// Explicitly check that it exists
if (Session["New1"] != null)
{
      // Then grab it (if it is a non-string type, then you can use as to cast it
      // (e.g. a List might use Session["List"] as List<Widget>;)
      Label1.Text = Convert.ToString(Session["New1"]);
}
else
{
        // Do something here
}
```

This assumes that your value will be set prior to this code getting called. Additionally, any hiccups to the web server (e.g. timeouts, restarts, major exceptions, etc.) will clear all of the values within the Session.